# Environment Variables are not able to pick from azure in NextJS

Tags: azure, next.js, deployment, github-actions, cicd

I Deployed my NextJs website on Azure through the CI/CD pipeline from GitHub actions but I can't able to access those environment variables that i configured on the Configuration app settings of Azure below is my code for accessing those environment variables:

I tried many approaches but remained unsuccessful and I have used the NextJs app router,

AzureConfiguration Env Variables:

key                                   Value
PROJECT_1                             project_1
API_KEY                               next_public_api_key
React_app                             new_react_app

and they all are coming as undefined

```
"use client";
import React from "react";

const page = () => {
    console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY);
    console.log(process.env.PROJECT_1);
    console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_React_app);
    return (
        <div>
            Next js app {process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY} {process.env.PROJECT_1}{" "}
            {process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_React_app}{" "}
        </div>
    );
};

export default page;
```

Github WorkFlow File:

```
name: Azure Deployment

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main  # Change this to your main branch name

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install dependencies and build
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build

      - name: Deploy to Azure
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: your-app-name  # Replace with your Azure app name
          slot-name: production  # Replace with your slot name if applicable
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}  # Your Azure publish profile secret
          package: .next
```

I tried all the possible approaches but the values always came as undefined

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256427/discussion-on-question-by-sahil-jaiswal-environment-variables-are-not-able-to-pi); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

- If you are deploying the app using GitHub Actions,you need to add the Variables with same name in `Git Hub Secrets`.

[image]

***My Secrets:***
[image]

- Edit the `yaml` file and include the above secrets in `Deploy to Azure  Action`.

```cs
publish-profile: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY }}
```

- The Environment Variables added in teh Configuration section will be availabel with prefix `APPSETTING`.
- AFAIK,we can read the values with `process.env.APPSETTING_NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY` when we deploy the app from VSCode other than the GitHub actions.
- Using GitHub Secrets is the better approach when we deploy using GitHub Actions.

Refer a blog on how to  [Deploying a App to Azure App Services via GitHub](https://techbrij.com/azure-app-services-github-deploying-mean)  by TechBrij for more details.

> approach of read the variables from the azure configuration setting

If you don't want to add secrets, you can add the environment variables in `yaml` as

```cs
${{ env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY }}
```

Also refer GitHub links [1](https://github.com/Azure/actions-workflow-samples/blob/master/AppService/node.js-webapp-on-azure.yml) and [2](https://github.com/Azure/actions-workflow-samples/blob/master/AppService/python-webapp-on-azure.yml) which explains the same.